# How to check if the same file name matches in 2 directories and append it using python?

Tags: python, dataframe, string-matching, fnmatch

> I have 2 directories with multiple files(read as CSV). The filename denotes a particular customer number.
>   I read the files as follows,

```
for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk("/path/to/file/"):
    for file in files:
        directory1(os.path.join(dirpath, file))
```

> I read these files as CSV.
>
> > If a directory2 filename(file) matches a filename in directory1 then I want to append the data together as one file.
> >
> > > If the filename(file) is not present in directory1 then copy the data as it is.
> > >
> > > > This new files should be saved to a new directory.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following:

```
import os
import glob
import shutil

dir1 = "/path/to/dir1/"
dir2 = "/path/to/dir2/"
new_dir = "/path/to/dir3/"
fpaths_dir1 = glob.glob(os.path.join(dir1, '*.csv'))
fpaths_dir1 = [os.path.basename(fpath) for fpath in fpaths_dir1]
fpaths_dir2 = glob.glob(os.path.join(dir2, '*.csv'))
fpaths_dir2 = [os.path.basename(fpath) for fpath in fpaths_dir2]

for fpath in fpaths_dir1:
    if fpath in fpaths_dir2:
        f1 = os.path.join(dir1, fpath)
        f2 = os.path.join(dir2, fpath)
        # write your code to open both files
        # and contatenate
    else:
        f1 = os.path.join(dir1, fpath)
        f3 = os.path.join(new_dir, fpath)
        shutil.copyfile(f1, f3)
```

`append the data together as one file` i leave it to you, kindly let me know if any issues..

Comment: How do I open 2 matching filenames among 1000s of files?

Comment: `f1` and `f2` are the matching files, you need to just concatenate those files